# HDRI and top view

Tags: camera, hdri

As you can see, I'm trying to make a car cinematic, with a top view of the scene. I added this HDRI that seemed cool when the camera is horizontal to the bridge, showing only the buildings.

What do you recommend? I'm willing to replace the HDRI if needed, or removing it for a better alternative.

Help will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, this is totally up to personal preferences and opinion-based, not a specific problem to which a solution can be found.

Comment: And HDRI is meant to be used for lighting up your scene first. Being a background is the last thing it can do. The point of view of the HDR is and will always be the camera that took it. If you happen to do a render with a similar camera position and angle than your HDRI, that can work. But you can't expect your HDRI taken from someone on the ground to look in place in a scene where the camera is basically a flying drone. You can maybe try to reorient the HDRI a bit via a mapping node, but that's about it.

Comment: Hello and welcome. This question is considered off topic here and was put on hold for being subjective and attracting opinion based answers, because there are no "right" or "wrong" answers and every suggestion is equally valid. For art critique, tips, artistic input, or other opinion based suggestions it is best to ask over at [Blender Artists Forum](https://blenderartists.org/) or similar forums. If you can rephrase it to focus on objective questions or solving specific issues feel free to [edit] it so it can be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

You could place a plane with a "Water" material under your scene:

[image: Water1]

You have to line up the camera carefully, though, so you don't see the parts you want hidden:

[image: Water2]

The problem is. you might not be able to get the angle you like, and without extra effort, the "cutoff" at the edge may seem unnatural. Perhaps you could blur it slightly in the compositor afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that did the trick 